# What is the performance characteristics of NSDirectoryEnumerator' fileAttributes method?

Tags: performance, cocoa, filesystems

How expensive is it to call the fileAttributes method when iterating over a directory?

In particular, I'd like to check if a path being enumerated is a directory. Is it better to use the fileAttributes dictionary or the file manager? (example below)

```
NSString *path = "/User/Jack/Documents";
NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [filemanager enumeratorAtPath:path];
NSString *file;
BOOL isDir;
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"File: %@", file);
    NSString * p = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    BOOL isDir1;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:p isDirectory:&isDir1];
    BOOL isDir2 = [[dirEnum fileAttributes] objectForKey:@"NSFileType"] == NSFileTypeDirectory;
    NSLog(@"isDirectory using fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory: = %d", isDir1);
    NSLog(@"isDirectory using FileAttributes = %d", isDir2);        
}
```

`fileAttributes` returns a ton of "unnecessary" information in addition to just isDirectory, here's a sample output

```
2011-12-23 16:17:40.523 App[10190:707] File Attributes: {
    NSFileCreationDate = "2011-10-23 04:04:51 +0000";
    NSFileExtensionHidden = 0;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID = 80;
    NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName = admin;
    NSFileModificationDate = "2011-10-23 04:07:52 +0000";
    NSFileOwnerAccountID = 501;
    NSFileOwnerAccountName = Tony;
    NSFilePosixPermissions = 493;
    NSFileReferenceCount = 6;
    NSFileSize = 204;
    NSFileSystemFileNumber = 8381694;
    NSFileSystemNumber = 234881029;
    NSFileType = NSFileTypeDirectory;
}
```

Whereas calling fileManager seems wasteful as well since we are already enumerating the directory in question.

Any insights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On most file systems both methods would take the same time to check if a file exists and to check if it is a directory because it would be necessary to access the inode data in addition to the directory entry data. This would be equivalent to a "[stat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28Unix%29)" call per file.

Getting the (full) file attribute requires to additionally read information about the file. The inode contains the information about the file size, the type, etc. Each file attributes call might require an extra IO read operation (Any caches are ignored here).

However, HFS/HFS+ is different. It is special in that is stores the file type in the directory entry ([Source Code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/dirent.h)). Therefore you can check if a file is a directory without accessing the inode information. NSFileManager's `fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` should be much faster. Possible, this only really matters if hundreds or thousands of files are involved, but it should be faster anyway.

BTW: ext4 also a [similar feature](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/articles/e/x/t/Ext4_Disk_Layout_aecb.html) unless the "filetype" flag is disabled.